# Bower_components in grunt and Git

Tags: gruntjs, bower, githooks

Hello all I'm after general opinions here.

My scenario is that when I'm building websites or web apps I tend to use grunt or gulp as a task runner. I drop in my dev dependencies via the help of bower and I'm using GIT for my version control.

In my repo I have a post-receive hook that exports repo to another folder on server that is accessible for previewing via http.

During the development phase I have all files/folders etc split into a nice MVC pattern but these can get compiled/minified into a single file with a task I have listed in my grunt file. I do this at staging/production, but for development /debugging i keep it all separated.

What's the best way to cater for the bower_components folder with GIT. I want them exported onto server but not sure that I need to be tracking them through GIT as they are maintained by their own authors.

Any thoughts or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are few opinions about adding bower_components to the git.

To keep in git:

**+** "No strange issues with backend-team". I don't know why, but from time to time somebody has problems like "I just do bower install and nothing work". (I think this happens because somebody make `bower install -F` when others do just without `-F` flag)

Not to keep:

**-** There is no point to keep libs history. Seriously.

**-** Once I'm saw the issue when one guy cannot even pull from git(windows) just because somebody make `bower instal jquery --save` and `bower instal jQuery --save` (on linux).  There were 2 folders (jquery and jQuery) which windows cannot resolve